# What is the ds:0023:003a3000=?? stuff on the end of a drwatson FAULT?

Tags: c++, logging, access-violation, postmortem-debugging, drwatson

I have the following entry in a Dr Watson log.  What is the significance of the "ds:0023:003a3000=??" part of the entry to the right of the FAULT line?

```
*----> State Dump for Thread Id 0xdfc <----*
eax=00000000 ebx=00390320 ecx=0854ff48 edx=09e44bfc esi=00012ce1 edi=0854ff61
eip=00465c51 esp=0854ff30 ebp=00000000 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010246

function: sysman
        00465c37 49               dec     ecx
        00465c38 eb02             jmp     sysman+0x65c3c (00465c3c)
        00465c3a 33c9             xor     ecx,ecx
        00465c3c 8d542428         lea     edx,[esp+0x28]
        00465c40 52               push    edx
        00465c41 51               push    ecx
        00465c42 8d4c2418         lea     ecx,[esp+0x18]
        00465c46 e8d5c0fcff       call    sysman+0x31d20 (00431d20)
        00465c4b 33c0             xor     eax,eax
        00465c4d 8d4c2418         lea     ecx,[esp+0x18]
FAULT ->00465c51 8a441eff         mov     al,[esi+ebx-0x1]        ds:0023:003a3000=??
        00465c55 50               push    eax
        00465c56 6864074900       push    0x490764
        00465c5b 51               push    ecx
        00465c5c e8cfd0fcff       call    sysman+0x32d30 (00432d30)
        00465c61 8d542424         lea     edx,[esp+0x24]
        00465c65 68689f4800       push    0x489f68
        00465c6a 8d44242c         lea     eax,[esp+0x2c]
        00465c6e 52               push    edx
        00465c6f 50               push    eax
        00465c70 e83bc3fcff       call    sysman+0x31fb0 (00431fb0)

*----> Stack Back Trace <----*
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 sysman+0x65c51

*----> Raw Stack Dump <----*
000000000854ff30  58 01 55 08 75 07 c8 09 - 00 00 00 00 18 6d c7 01  X.U.u........m..
000000000854ff40  fc 4b e4 09 04 bd 47 00 - 04 bd 47 00 fc 0c c9 01  .K....G...G.....
000000000854ff50  ac ca ae 09 64 5f c4 01 - 20 37 37 30 32 34 3a 20  ....d_.. 77024: 
000000000854ff60  00 b3 42 00 a8 ff 54 08 - 90 a6 47 00 02 00 00 00  ..B...T...G.....
000000000854ff70  8b c5 42 00 b8 ff 54 08 - 2e 03 39 00 28 99 cb 01  ..B...T...9.(...
000000000854ff80  ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 20 1e cb 01  ............ ...
000000000854ff90  a6 f7 ba 77 06 00 00 00 - c9 f7 ba 77 e1 6b d9 09  ...w.......w.k..
000000000854ffa0  06 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 - 68 00 55 08 c1 a0 47 00  ........h.U...G.
000000000854ffb0  00 00 00 00 58 c4 42 00 - c9 a5 ca 09 d1 fb 38 0a  ....X.B.......8.
000000000854ffc0  27 00 00 00 e1 6b d9 09 - ef f2 41 00 c9 a5 ca 09  '....k....A.....
000000000854ffd0  01 59 cc 01 38 00 55 08 - ec 00 55 08 00 00 00 00  .Y..8.U...U.....
000000000854ffe0  e0 00 55 08 ff ff ff ff - 89 00 00 00 01 00 01 01  ..U.............
000000000854fff0  c8 ff 54 08 b8 ff 54 08 - 77 00 55 08 29 a5 ca 09  ..T...T.w.U.)...
0000000008550000  51 00 00 00 5f 00 00 00 - 00 9f 82 7c 61 36 ca 01  Q..._......|a6..
0000000008550010  25 00 00 00 3f 00 00 00 - 00 ce bb 77 91 b7 c7 01  %...?......w....
0000000008550020  19 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 - 00 ff ff ff d9 28 cc 01  .............(..
0000000008550030  0b 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 - 00 00 55 08 d1 fb 38 0a  ..........U...8.
0000000008550040  27 00 00 00 3f 00 00 00 - 00 20 ba 77 00 00 00 00  '...?.... .w....
0000000008550050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 20 b7 c7 01 00 00 00 00  ........ .......
0000000008550060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - b4 00 55 08 1b 90 47 00  ..........U...G.`
```

Comment: It's telling you the computed value of `esi + ebx - 0x1`, which is the address that failed to be read from.

Comment: cs=code segment ss=stack segment  ds=data segment; all anachronisms of 16-bit segmented real-mode DOS.  `mov     al,[esi+ebx-0x1]        ds:0023:003a3000=??` says the address pointed to by `ds:[esi+ebx-1]` is bogus; hence your access violation.

Comment: Actually, cs, ds and so on do have a meaning in 32 and 64-bit mode too. Mainly to determine the "ring" (user-mode=3 or kernel-mode=0 in the lower 2 bits of the value, so this is data accessed as user mode).

Comment: Thanks @DCoder, how about the '0023' part?

Comment: That's the value of `ds` segment register, which is also involved in that instruction. Start by reading Mats Petersson's comment, continue to the [Intel x86 Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize:

You get a register dump here:

```
eax=00000000 ebx=00390320 ecx=0854ff48 edx=09e44bfc esi=00012ce1 edi=0854ff61
eip=00465c51 esp=0854ff30 ebp=00000000 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010246
```

The `eip` indicates the instruction that failed:

```
FAULT ->00465c51 8a441eff         mov     al,[esi+ebx-0x1]        ds:0023:003a3000=??
```

The stuff at the end is the address that failed to read, which is the "usual" data segment of 23, and address 3A3000, whcih is composed of `esi` and `ebx` minus 1: 390320+12ce1-1. To me, that looks like an index gone bad - 3a3000 would be the first address of a new "page" in memory, so that's why it's failing at that point. 77025 bytes into an array is quite a long way, but it is of course possible that it's something else that is wrong.